# What if we need few trackOutboundLink on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I already have 1 outbound link on my page ([just like in this example](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en)). Everything works perfectly. But what if I have to track down the download button **on the same page**...what should I add to my HTML document? Thanks.

Comment: Try google tag manager. https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6102821?hl=en

Comment: Thanks a lot! Already set up, everything works fine.